# phpmyadmin not longer working after updating ubuntu LTS12.04 to ubuntu LTS14.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql

After I upgraded Ubuntu 12.04LTS to Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I found that phpmyadmin is no longer working by calling `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`. It did work on before upgrading.

Now I get this when trying to go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: Do the other projects work?

Answer (score 1):

The default path to served files in Ubuntu 14.04 has changed from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html`, mainly for security reasons.

The packaging has been overhauled quite significantly. `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` is now `/etc/apache2/conf-available/` and `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`, to match the existing `sites-enabled/` and `mods-enabled/` mechanisms.

The simplest way to enable phpmyadmin is to create symlink of `phpmyadmin.conf` and place it in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/` folder and then restart the server. It did work for me.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

(ref: http://www.justgohome.co.uk/blog/2014/04/new-in-14-04-apache.html)

Comment: You could use the `a2enconf` and `a2disconf` commands instead of manually creating links.